# Why is this variable creating an UnboundLocalError?

Tags: python, caching, python-decorators

I am trying to create a wrapper which uses the function name and string representations of arguments to create a caching key.

I have tried the following and for some reason am getting `NameError`

```py
>>> def cache_key_gen(func):
...     key = func.__name__
...     def wrapper(*args):
...             global key
...             print(key)
...             for arg in args:
...                     key += str(arg)
...             print(key)
...             return func(*args)
...     return wrapper
...
>>> @cache_key_gen
... def add(x, y):
...     return  x + y
...
>>> add(1,2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in wrapper
NameError: name 'key' is not defined
```

When I have tried the following I am getting `UnboundLocalError`

```py
>>> def cache_key_gen(func):
...     key = func.__name__
...     def wrapper(*args):
...             for arg in args:
...                     key += str(arg)
...             print(key)
...             return func(*args)
...     return wrapper
...
>>> @cache_key_gen
... def add(x, y):
...     return  x + y
...
>>> add(1,2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in wrapper
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'key' referenced before assignment
```

I am confused, what did I miss. This seems to be either a basic silly mistake or some behavior about decorators that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`key` is not global; it is *nonlocal*, being defined in `cache_key_gen`.

```
def cache_key_gen(func):
...     key = func.__name__
...     def wrapper(*args):
...             nonlocal key
...             print(key)
...             for arg in args:
...                     key += str(arg)
...             print(key)
...             return func(*args)
...     return wrapper
```